# How to write and run python codes on web browser without OS installation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-standalone

For various reasons, I can't install a full python into my Windows machine.

With that constraint in mind, how can I write and run python without installation in my desktop, and particularly on web browsers? I have come across the [Jupyter demo](https://try.jupyter.org/), but it's only a demo version.

If possible, it will be best if I can "install" needed libraries.

Comment: you can try repl.it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several online solutions, like: [Try It Online](https://tryitonline.net/), [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python3).

You can also find a online virtual machine:

- https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-online-virtual-linux-machine

Comment: Would it be possible for repl.it to interact with databases stored in my local drive?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner and need to execute basic code without installing any libraries on your host machine, then you can use the following website:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/try_python.php